# Share enum class between web api solution and client solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, enums

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api with .NET Framework 4.0 and C#.

I'm using this:

```
HttpError myCustomError = new HttpError(errorMessage) { { "CustomErrorCode", 12 } };
```

I want to change that `12` with an enum and share that `enum` class with all clients. How can I do it?

I've thought to create that `enum` in a project and share that project with a C# client that I'm developing.

Is there another better approach?

I don't want to have two copies of the same class in Web Api solution and another one in my client solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, we use a Common library, which is referenced both in server and client.
It allows to develop C# clients and also it not breakes other clients written in PHP, Javascript, etc.

I think it is the cleanest solution, actually, the projects are growing and growing, so the amount of shared data increases and you already have a place to keep it.